# SQL: Union of two tables which don't have full column match

Tags: sql, oracle, union

I have a `table_A` which has a set of column `A1`,`A2` and a table_b which has a set of columns `B1`,`B2`

It happens that `A2=B1` but the rest of the columns don't match (and are not supposed to). I would like to append the table so I use `UNION ALL`

For non matching columns, I use `null as COLUMN_NAME`, on both sides of the `UNION` statement

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS 
SELECT
TABLE_A.A1,
TABLE_A.A2,
null as B2
from TABLE_A
union all
SELECT 
null as A1,
TABLE_B.B1 as A2,
TABLE_B.B2 as B2
from TABLE_B;
```

which outputs the following error:

```
Error report: SQL Error: ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression 01790. 00000 - "expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression"
```

Is it because of the nulls?

Comment: The problem is that you've put the columns in a different order in each half of the union. The columns have to match up, in the same order, between the two halves.

Comment: Can't say, are we assuming that the types of a2 and b1 re the same.

Comment: they are the same type

Comment: @Andrey looks to be right then, though personally I wouldn't have bother with the casts and the aliases in the second select.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to explicitly cast NULLs to appropriate types in the upper `SELECT`.

```
CREATE VIEW MY_VIEW AS 
SELECT
TABLE_A.A1,
TABLE_A.A2,
CAST(null AS <type_of_TABLE_B_B2>) as B2
from TABLE_A
union all
SELECT 
null,
TABLE_B.B1,
TABLE_B.B2
from TABLE_B;
```

---

As for the alternatives as **@evilive** says you can use fixed values as empty string (`''`) for VARCHARs or zero for NUMBERs but for my opinion explicit cast is better solution because it is obvious and will not cause a surprises

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1037c/1)

Comment: is this the only way or is there an alternative one? I have more than 50 columns so I'd love to avoid some casts

Comment: @Stephane - you only need to cast the explicit nulls, not all of the columns; and only in the first branch of the union (as Tony Hopkinson mentioned; the aliases aren't used in the second branch either). Presumably you only have a small proportion, not all 50.

Comment: need to try :) I am currently waiting for SQLFiddle to build example schema and will try some variants

Comment: If you don't want to cast null-values you could select fixed values of the needed type, i.e. empty string for varchars (`''`) or zero for numbers. But it's a little dirty of course, cause it differs from null in further processing...

Comment: Stephane - you asked about alternatives. The short answer is No, @Andrey got it right. But the other path is to ask whether a union of the 2 tables is the right way to go. Not knowing your actual situation (requirements, context, etc.), I can't really say. But when I saw that you are unioning 2 tables with over 50 columns and many mismatches, my first thought was, "I wonder why."

Comment: well there is reason. One query in up to 2013 that has changed in 2014. You have a common denominator but few differences. As we want to do an analysis cross year we have to union these tables. Makes sense?