# CAST error to NUMBER(17,5) in SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, casting, numbers

I am using Oracle SQL

This works:

```
SELECT 
CAST(null as NUMBER(17)) AS COL1
FROM TABLE_A
UNION ALL
SELECT 
TABLE_B.COL1 AS COL1
FROM TABLE_B
```

But this doesn't:

```
SELECT 
CAST(null as NUMBER(17,5)) AS COL1
FROM TABLE_A
UNION ALL
SELECT 
TABLE_B.COL1 AS COL1
FROM TABLE_B
```

It throws the following error:

```
Error(s) parsing SQL:
Unexpected token near *!* in the following:
CAST(null as NUMBER(17*!*,5)) AS COL1
```

Can I not convert to a NUMBER(17,5)?

NB: COL1 's type is NUMBER(17,5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) But what stops you to write this way :

```
SELECT 
TABLE_B.COL1 AS COL1
FROM TABLE_B
UNION ALL
SELECT 
CAST(null as NUMBER(17)) AS COL1
FROM TABLE_A
```

2)

> Error(s) parsing SQL: Unexpected token near *!* in the following:

Is not an Oracle error.

3)

```
SELECT 
CAST(null as NUMBER(17,5)) AS COL1
FROM dual;
```

works fine in my environment

Comment: related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27800482/sql-union-of-two-tables-which-dont-have-full-column-match

I have null on both ends

Comment: you solved my issue... looks like it was a SQL Developer issue, not Oracle related